# Upgrading to 12.10 on an external hard drive

Tags: 12.04

I did some googling on this and didn't find anything specific for my situation.

I currently have 12.04 installed on an external USB hard drive. It's working great. I want to upgrade it to 12.10. My bandwidth is very limited so I have a friend who will download 12.10 for me and put it on a flash stik. Then I can upgrade without having to do the download myself.

Which particular version of the 12.10 download file(s) should I get? Are there alternate 12.10 downloads that have all the packages?

How do I set it up so when I upgrade 12.04 I can specify that it look in some local repository for the 12.10 files? Can I just dump the 12.10 files in some local directory? Or do I have do go thru some complex commands to create a local repository?

I'm pretty new to Linux so a long process of complex terminal commands will probably be a show stopper for me.

Remember that my 12.04 install resides on an external hard drive. And I have a laptop with multiple USB ports.

Thanks!

Advait

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no method of Upgrading Ubuntu from Flash/USB drive, you can only upgrade through internet.Else the easiest method is to backup all your data from Ubuntu 12.04 and then do complete reinstall of Ubuntu 12.10 on your external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the standard ubuntu-desktop.iso.

You can use the downloaded ubuntu.iso to create a bootable installation CD / USB using 'Start Up Disk Creator' or 'Unetbootin'.

When you boot your computer using that CD / USB, select Install Ubuntu and there should be an option to Upgrade 12.04 to 12.10.

If you have problems or the option does not appear, you could take the laptop & USB HDD to your friends house, or just the USB HDD to your friends computer, boot the USB HDD on that computer, then connect to their internet and update it to 12.10.